# Setup WAF for App Services without Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

I am searching for a way to enable WAF for my App Services but I don't want to use Application Gateway instead I am wondering if it is possible to configure WAF in the app services itself. Need some help on this.

Answer (score 1):

No,

besides Azure Application Gateway, the only service that offers WAF is Azure Front Door.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternative. I want to protect my website from most common security vulnerabilities. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: WAF is the right way. You can use Azure Front Door, Azure Application Gateway or some other 3rd party e.g. Cloudflare.

Comment: If you don't want to use Azure AppGateway or Frontdoor, then a third party provider is the only option. Honestly, the Azure WAF is average at best anyway.